# Handling JAXBElement<Byte> Soaprequest in SpringWS

Tags: soap, jaxb, arrays, spring-ws, jaxbelement

Am having below enpoint method. Here am struct with processing the Soaprequest.

```
public JAXBElement<com.schema.get_response.v2.GetResponseType> handleGetresponse(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<Byte> Soaprequest){
.......................................
/* how to process the Soaprequest which contains the byte[] of base64Binary objects*/
}
```

My webservices is hitting the above endpoint and the Soap request is having JAXBElement byte[] of base64Binary objects.Am facing an issue with processing the above  JAXBElement request object and getting the actual request from that. please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewritten the above method declaration like below, it worked out.

```
public JAXBElement<com.schema.get_response.v2.GetResponseType> handleGetresponse(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<String> Soaprequest){
.......................................
/* how to process the Soaprequest which contains the byte[] of base64Binary objects*/
}
```

change description: 
Declaration changed from JAXBElement<Byte> to JAXBElement<String>